# How to set button color in ZK

Tags: java, html

There is a button in the code:

```
<button type = "button" style = "background-color: #088ADE"> Save </button>
```

But the button color does not change. How to set button color attribute correctly?

Comment: How this question related to java?

Comment: The code is produced by the Java ZK web framework, I guess. To find the attribute that will work for the button, go into your browser inspector (in the debugging console) and edit the components live until you find the correct one, then consult the ZK framework documentation for that, and then come and answer your own question... Also add "ZK framework in Java" to your question title, so as to not confuse people. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space between `#` and color code and it shall work.

`# 088ADE` to `#088ADE`

```html
<button type = "button" style = "background-color: #088ADE"> Save </button>
```

Comment: did you run the code snippet? the background color has changed,

Comment: Yes, I run the code snippet, but my button color still does not change

Comment: Try this "background-color: #088ADE !important;" on your code.

Comment: still no change

Comment: From my side, I am seeing the color has changed from the runnable code snippet across multiple browsers like chrome, firefox and edge. Sorry, I could not think of other possible solution.